# Why does the cast operation fail in case 1 but succeed in case 2?

Tags: c#

Case 1 produces a type mismatch exception.  Case 2 works as expected.  Does anyone have insight into why? Or a better way to have converted from Int32 as an object into an Int16?

Case 1:

```
var i = (Int16)(object)Int32.Parse("1");
```

Case 2:

```
var i = (Int16)Int32.Parse("1");
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741788/why-does-this-cast-from-short-to-int-fail and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/

Comment: @filhit.  thank you for the excellent references.  the SO is close to what caused this question to arise.  The links help answer why.

Comment: @GregBogumil Why the hell don't you just use `Int16.Parse("1");`?

Comment: @Mikanikal good question.  The code was actually converted to int i = (Int32)dataRow[colIndex]; which prevents the conversion error from the unboxed data type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The underlying cause is the fact that in C# the explicit cast operator has two different meanings:

- The *representation-preserving* meaning is: "I know this object is always of type T, even though the compiler couldn't prove it statically - please let me use it as T instead of something more general".
- The *representation-changing* meaning is: "I know this object *isn't* of type T, but there is a conversion to turn it into T and I'd like that conversion to be performed".

So the reason you're getting two different behaviors is that you are using each of the above different meanings respectively:

- Your first snippet says: "I know that this `object` *is definitely* a boxed `Int16` and I'd like to use it as such". But since it's actually a boxed `Int32`, you get a type mismatch exception.
- Your second snippet says: "I know that this `Int32` *is definitely not* an `Int16`, but I'd like to convert it to one".

In other words, unboxing works only if you attempt to unbox to the original type. [According to Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/), the reason is that it was simply too impractical to implement it in a way that it could unbox and convert in a single operation.

Comment: Great article from Eric Lippert.

Comment: things are always much simpler on the outside of the framework.  I seems that, once unboxed, a type check could lead to the conversion call happening.  That's my comment after only considering the article for a couple minutes though.  I expect there are numerous pitfalls along that path which are less desirable than the current behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As Damian correctly commented, I was wrong. The problem wasn't the conversion, the problem lies in the unboxing operation. *It only allows unboxing from an object from the same type it was originally boxed from.*

`int > object > int` is okay, `int > object > short` isn't and so is `short > object > int`.

This will only work if the `int` was first converted to a short, like so:`int > short > object > short` is fine.

This particular case is even used in an [unboxing sample on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I am running the case 1 under visual studio 2012, and it compiles without any errors.

Comment: It compiles but doesn't execute.

Comment: I was trying to find where these conversions were defined. Do you happen to know where? I'd love to check it out.

Comment: Looking for it too, but clearly this is the reason why.

Comment: Of course there's a conversion from `object` to `short` - it's called unboxing, and it's a defined concept for all `struct`s - it's just that you have to unbox to the same type that was boxed.

Comment: E.g. the line `var i1 = (Int16)(object)Int16.Parse("1");` would be absolutely fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. Clearly my mistake. Updated my post.

Comment: @Nasreddine: They are defined in the chapter of the C# specification on conversions.

Comment: A small nit: you can unbox a `T` only to `T` *or* `T?`.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks. I thought about tweeting you this question but I figured that you might have more important things to do.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case your are trying to `unbox` an `Int32` typed value into a `Int16` typed field, which gives you the type-mismatch exception since there is no implicit conversion available to cast from `object` to `Int32`.

In your second case you are directly casting an `Int32` to an `Int16`. Since this is a direct cast here you'll get the benefit of `implicit type conversion` ([see this MSDN article for a more detailed explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)).